# How to create multiple variables in java indexed by numbers?

Tags: java

I'm making some code, and just realized that I need to create many variables. For instance,
I want to create multiple variables that all of them are similar, except just in the index.

Instead of doing 50 times

```
student1  = new student(param1, param2, param3, etc)
...
student50  = new student(param1, param2, param3, etc)
```

I was thinking of something like

```
For (int i=1; i<50; i++ ){
  student i   = new student(param1, param2, param3, etc)
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Variables in java cannot have "dynamic" names. What you want is a List or array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array or a `List`. (Note: in Java, it is best for class names to be capitalized.)

```java
student[] students = new student[50];
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  students[i] = new student(/* ... */);
}
// access like students[0] for first student
```